# How to get the data of my fetch result and place it in my components

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Im trying to fetch data, Im getting the data, but im not able to share the content with my components. I think it's because im missing something regarding to how Im getting the data (array, map) Im totally confused, hopefully somebody can help me.

First of all if a user visits my site, im fetching initially data with this function:

```
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  const posts = await prisma.post.findMany({
    orderBy: [
      {
        createdAt: 'desc',
      },],
    take: 3,
  })
  return {
    props: { posts }
  }
}
```

if we `console.log(posts)` the result is a list of objects: `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`

Now im saving the post objects inside a `useState`:

```
const [feed, setFeed] = useState(props.posts)
```

and place it into my component:

```
{
      feed ? feed.map(post => {
       
        <PostBasic post={post}></PostBasic>
      }) : 'loading...'}
```

Until this point everything works perfectly fine. Now I extended my code to have a load more button which will fetch more posts if the user is pressing the button. This is the function for it:

```
async function fetchMoreData() {
    const fetchedData = await axios.get('/api/fetchfeed', {params:{dataCount: feed.length}})
    console.log(fetchedData.data)
    if(fetchedData.data.length != 0){
     

        setFeed([...feed, fetchedData.data[0]])
// Im lost here, something is missing
      
      return feed
    } else {
      setFeedEnd(true)
      return feed
    }
    
  }
```

if we `console.log(fetchedData.data)` Im receiving an array:

```
[{…}]
0: {id: 2, createdAt: "2021-06-10T10:13:46.814Z", exchangedAt: "2021-06-10T11:31:18.042Z", imageUrl: "http://res.cloudinary.com/...", user: "user12", …}
length: 5
```

And here Im stuck. I need to transform the array to have the same result as my initialdata to add the data with `setFeed()` so my components can access the data again. Please help

Comment: In what way are the returned arrays different?

Comment: setFeed([...feed, ...fetchedData.data]) . Also it's not clear why you are returning the `feed` ?

Comment: If i do this: setFeed([...feed, ...fetchedData.data]) nothing changes. I still have my initialdata lets say 5 posts and the other 5 posts from fetchedData.data arent displayed in my component. there are there if i console.log but they arent for my components

Comment: Im returning the feed, because im saving the initialdata in a usestate const [feed, setFeed] = useState(props.posts) and i want to add the data from the load more to the feed too. Thats why im returning feed

Comment: You need to use a callback in your setFeed call, otherwise you create a closure over the initial state value at the time the function is declared. `setFeed(currFeed => [...currFeed, ...fetchedData.data])`. Also you don't need a return, the setFeed handles updating the state.

Comment: @pilchard thanks for the assistance. The fetchedData.data is still not in the feed if I console log it. Why doesnt it beeing added? What else is missing here?